# How to display posts from custom post type category(custom Taxonomy) wise?

Tags: wp-query, custom-taxonomy

I have created a site where i have a custom post type as Resources. I have a custom taxonomy(Resources Topics) attached to it.

I want to show them in a card system where there will be taxonomy image, taxonomy name and the posts assosicated to it.

[image]

Something Like this. The Images are taxonomy images which i have added using ACF plugin. The Process Efficiency, Vendor Diversity, Management and leadership etc are taxonomy term name and the below list is the posts list from that taxonomy term. The "SEE MORE" Button will link you to the category archive page. I want everything to be dynamic.

I am stuck on the query. I can do the style if someone can help me out with the query in this structure.

I have searched over the internet but couldn't found a solution.
Any type of help will be appreciated.

Comment: You'll need to query for posts either via [`get_posts()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_posts/) or [a new `WP_Query` instance](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#standard-loop). Refer to [the `WP_Query` documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#parameters) for the keys/values accepted into either's argument as an associative array. If you make an attempt and get stuck, share the code you have and we can help you out from there.

Answer (score 0):

You can start with [get_terms()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_terms/) to get the topic terms. This can be wrapped in a helper function so that you don't have to specify the parameters every time you use `get_terms()`. Additionally with the helper function you can force the return value to always be an array. E.g.

```
function my_resources_topic_terms() {
  $topics = get_terms( array(
    'taxonomy' => 'resources_topics',
    'hide_empty' => true,
  ) );
  return is_array( $topics ) ? $topics : [];
}
```

As bosco pointed out in the comments use `get_posts()` or `new WP_Query()` to retrieve posts. You'lle need to use `tax_query` parameter to limit the query to specific term(s). The query can also be wrapped in a helper function to make it reusable and to utilise default parameters. E.g.

```
function my_resources_posts_by_topic( WP_Term $topic ) {
  $query = new WP_Query([
    'post_type' => 'resources',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => 3,
    'no_found_rows' => true,
    'update_post_meta_cache' => false,
    'update_post_term_cache' => false,
    'tax_query' => [
      [
        'taxonomy' => 'resources_topics',
        'field' => 'term_id',
        'terms' => $topic->term_id,
      ]
    ],
  ]);
  return $query->posts;
}
```

Then it is just a matter of looping a loop to get the terms and posts associated with them. Use the WP functions to retrieve the post links ([get_permalink()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_permalink/)) and the term archive link ([get_term_link()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_term_link/)). Term ([WP_Term](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_term/)) and post ([WP_Post](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_post/)) details, such as titles, are public [class properties](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php) and can be accessed directly with `->`. E.g.

```
foreach ( my_resources_topic_terms() as $topic_term ) {

  echo '<div class="topic">';

  printf(
    '<h2 class="topic__title">%s</h2>', 
    esc_html( $topic_term->name )
  );

  printf(
    '<ul class="topic__posts">%s</ul>',
    implode(
      '',
      array_map(
        function( WP_Post $topic_post ) {
          return sprintf(
            '<li class="topic__post">
              <a href="%s">%s</a>
            </li>',
            esc_url( get_permalink( $topic_post ) ),
            esc_html( $topic_post->post_title )
          );
        },
        my_resources_posts_by_topic( $topic_term )
      )
    )
  );

  printf(
    '<a class="topic__more" href="%s">%s</a>',
    esc_url( get_term_link( $topic_term ) ),
    esc_html__( 'See More', 'textdomain' )
  );

  echo '</div>';
  
}
```

Do note that, if you have a great number of topics, then you might experience some performance issues with the resulting multiple queries. You may want to consider caching the query results for example in [a transient](https://developer.wordpress.org/apis/handbook/transients/) and using some page caching mechanism.